# Syntax Error - Excel VLookup across 2 workbooks

Tags: excel, vlookup

bit of an excel noob. Been rummaging around trying to write some code that will allow me to somewhat automate a CSV edit for upload to an online storefront.
This is what I've come up with so far, but it's throwing me a syntax error in the compiler. Can anyone help me? I've tried a number of things regarding the link/path to the external workbook, which I suspected was the problem, but it doesn't seem to be resolving the issue, so I think I may have done something else wrong.

The code lines marked in red in the compiler are the 'MusiposAvail = Vlookup' and the 'If MusiposAvail = ' lines.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ShopifySKU As String
Dim MusiposAvail As String
Dim VariantPolicy As Boolean

Sub DROPSHIP()
 Range("N2").Select
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         ' Insert your code here.
         ShopifySKU = ActiveCell
         MusiposAvail = VLOOKUP(ShopifySKU, 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CSV FILES FOR DROPSHIPPING\[DROPSHIP.CSV]DROPSHIP'!$Q$2:$R$3123,2,FALSE)
         If MusiposAvail = N
         VariantPolicy = False
         Else: VariantPolicy = True
         End If
         
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, is the csv file open before running the macro? you could perhaps try using `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(ShopifySKU, Range("'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CSV FILES FOR DROPSHIPPING\[DROPSHIP.CSV]DROPSHIP'!$Q$2:$R$3123"),2,FALSE)`

Comment: I have both csv files that i'm attempting to use open. I am storing the macro separately in the PERSONAL.XLSB file, because the two csv files I'm using will change as they are replaced by new data.
Tried the 'Application.WorksheetFunction.' addition already, it hasn't fixed the issue. 
The error is actually "Expected:Expression"

Comment: Found some changes someone suggested for someone else on another site. Has fixed my error in the VLOOKUP code, now I just have issues in my IF statement, which is incomplete anyway.
`MusiposAvail = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(ShopifySKU), Workbooks("DROPSHIP.CSV").Sheets("DROPSHIP").Range("Q2:R3123"), 2, False)`